# Why are my bulma columns wrapping, despite not having is-multiline set?

Tags: css, bulma

I'm using Bulma for column management, and it has a `is-multiline` class that can be used to allow columns to wrap.  However, I'm not using this class, but my columns are still wrapping.

#### Expected Behavior:

Two columns are always side-by-side, on the same row

#### Actual behavior:

At certain viewport widths, the second column goes below the first column instead of beside.

#### Question

If you're familiar with Bulma, would you mind taking a look at this simple example and letting me know if I'm doing something obviously wrong? Thanks so much!

### HTML

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column row-name is-narrow">
      Row 1
    </div>
    <div class="column row-cells">
      Some data
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.body {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
.row-name {
  background-color: #ffff0088;
  width: 50px;
}
.row-cells {
  background-color: #ff000088;
}
```

A JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ggyagxp/10/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out if Bulma detects that your viewport is *mobile* sized, it will stack columns unless the `is-mobile` class exists on the columns.  See [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/) for more information.

Comment: I was wondering why the columns were stacking on top of each other even though both should fit in the same "row". Totally forgot about the is-mobile class. Thanks.